# AssertionError: The setup method 'route' can no longer be called on the blueprint 'routes'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, routes

I'm facing the following issue while running a flask blueprint application.

AssertionError: The setup method 'route' can no longer be called on the blueprint 'routes'. It has already been registered at least once, any changes will not be applied consistently.
Make sure all imports, decorators, functions, etc. needed to set up the blueprint are done before registering it.

Here is my server.py snippet:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from routes import routes

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(routes)
CORS(app)
```

and in routes folder I have the routes and the blueprint is initialized in **init**.py as follows:

```
from flask import Blueprint
routes = Blueprint('routes', __name__)

from .home import *
from .notFound import *
```

Can anyone help me understand how can I resolve this issue? Thanks